# How to Implement Conditionally Running of Tests in TestNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am stuck in a scenario, where user is allowed to rate the movie only once a day with same user credentials. 
If user tried to rate the same movie or contract, error pop_up seen.

I want to Implement in a way, that if once any movie/contract is rated. The rating functionality should be skipped and Error pop should be Handled.

I am using Selenium eclipse 2017, Chrome browser 61.0 and Test-Ng

Please help in the same.

Thanks.

```
public class Ratings {
String driverPath = "F:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver;
public Alert alert;

@BeforeTest
public void LaunchBrowser () throws InterruptedException {
System.out.println("WebBrowser open");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.e
xe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
@Test (priority = 1, alwaysRun = true)
public void HomePageUSA() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.navigate().to("Https://us.justdial.com");
    String expectedTitle = "Justdial US";
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    try
    {
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(expectedTitle, actualTitle);
    System.out.println("Test Passed");
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
@Test (priority = 2, dependsOnMethods = {"HomePageUSA"})
public void Login() throws Exception{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div
/div[4]/aside/div/span/a[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword3")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword3")).sendKeys("testing.testjd@gmail.c
om");
driver.findElement(By.id("exampleInputPassword1")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("exampleInputPassword1")).sendKeys("justdial");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div
[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/button")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
String expectedTitle = "Justdial US";
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
try
{
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle, actualTitle);
System.out.println("Login Successful");
}
catch (Throwable e)
{
System.out.println("Login Failed");
}
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='us-jdnew-
wrapper']/div[1]/div/header/div/div[1]/a[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
}
  @Test (priority = 3)
  public void Movies_Rating_page() throws Exception {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hotkeylnk106']/div[2]")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-

wrapper']/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/span/img")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-
wrapper']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/span/a[2]/span[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='AlreadyRated']/div/div/div/section/div/a")).click();
System.out.println("Rating Page Redirection Successful");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='us-jdnew-
wrapper']/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/span[10]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='us-jdnew-
wrapper']/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/textarea")).sendKeys("Very nice 
movie, Must watch.");   
Thread.sleep(1000); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='us-jdnew-
wrapper']/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/button[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Rating Successfully Submitted");
```

Comment: Can you please help share, what code you have so far, and where you are stuck and looking for help ?

Comment: Sure, Adding code.

Comment: @Vaibhav Singh in your application how do you know that user has rated? What is the behavioral change. Can you show the xpath for that change of element?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method and tag that method in your test method as `dependsOnMethods` . You can achieve it like below (i tried to answer to the best based on the info provided)

The idea here is that when your rated condition is met `isMovieRated` should throw exception so that `Movies_Rating_page()` will be skipped by testNG ,otherwise `isMovieRated` just returns `true` and nothing should be skip.

```
       @Test
       public static boolean isMovieRated(String locator) {

  //check in "if" below that element has already clicked or is equal to something. I used 'AlreadyClicked' just to 
     give an idea as I dont have your application information.

    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator).getText()=="AlreadyClicked"){
     throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    else {

    return true;

    }
}
```

Now your `Movies_Rating_page()` will look like this

```
@Test (priority = 3,dependsOnMethods = { "isMovieRated" })
  public void Movies_Rating_page() throws Exception {
   
   public static String YourLocator = "/html/body/...."
   Ratings.isMovieRated(YourLocator);
   ..
   }
```

[here](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-7-dependency-test/) is a link for more info on testNG `dependsOnMethods`

Note:

1. The code above is not tested.
2. If you are doing things other than checking rating in `Movies_Rating_page()` then you should separate those things because everything will be skipped when an exception is thrown.

   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Shall try same in my class.